# Trying to restructure JQuery for best practice but failing when declaring variable

Tags: jquery, variables

Based on a similar casestudy I've created the following bit of script to reveal/hide a signup form when clicking on a 'signup' image (with an 'X' to appear and act as a close button when the form shows:

```
(function($) {

    var container = $('#sidecontent'); 

    $('#signup').on('click', function () { 

        container.slideToggle(500); 

        if ( container.find('span.close').length ) return; 

        $('<span class=close>X</span>') 
            .prependTo(container) 
            .on('click', function () {
                container.slideToggle(500)
            })
    });

})(jQuery);
```

It seems to works fine. My problem is I think it probably isn't the best way to write it… but once I try to tidy up the code i.e. make  a  `var Mytoggle = $(container.slideToggle(500))`  that I recall things either fail or the form appears automatically.

I'm a Jquery newbie (and seem to run into trouble figuring out defining variables and object literal). Would appreciate any input on the best way to restructure the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
(function($) {
    var container = $('#sidecontent'),
        Mytoggle = function () {
            container.slideToggle(500);
        }


    $('#signup').on( 'click', function () { 
        Mytoggle();
        if ( container.find('span.close').length ) return; 

        $('<span class=close>X</span>') 
            .prependTo(container) 
            .on('click', function () {
                Mytoggle();
            })
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The function **Mytoggle** is defined outside the on-click-handler.

The code above could be improved further:

```
(function($) {
    var container = $('#sidecontent'),
        Mytoggle = function () {
            container.slideToggle(500);
        }

    // You can define this click handler here, even if span.close doesn't exist yet
    container.on('click', 'span.close', Mytoggle);


    $('#signup').on('click', function () { 
        Mytoggle();

        if (container.find('span.close').length === 0) {
            $('<span class="close">X</span>') 
            .prependTo(container);
        } 


    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @Pointy, @ TJ. Thanks very much to you both Pointy and TJ! 

That all works great. I didn't realise I'd need to add parentheses after Mytoggle as it's already been defined as a function. 

I was sure I'd been looking at examples were a similar sort of variable is called without them but now I'm routing around I can't find an example… I guess I have some rereading to do to make sense of things 

Anyway thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Probably should be

```
var myToggle = $(container).slideToggle(500);
```

*edit* — wait; you want that to be a function, right?

```
function myToggle() {
  container.slideToggle(500);
}
```

Then you can just call that, or pass it to set up the click handler:

```
   // ...
   .on('click', myToggle);
```

*edit again* — Since you're initializing "container" to be a jQuery variable, there's no reason to re-wrap it, so you can just use "container" directly to make jQuery calls.

Sometimes people use variable names with "$" at the start as a reminder:

```
var $container = $('#sidecontent');
```

That's a matter of personal preference.